# Proof that the argument is continuous on a cut plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to understand the following proof of continuity of the principal argument function
$$\text{Arg}:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{x\leq 0 : x \in \mathbb{R}\}\to \mathbb{R}$$
which takes $z \in X=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{x\leq 0 : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ to the unique $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$ such that $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$.

*Proof.* Let $re^{i\theta}$ and $se^{i\phi}$ be two points in $X$. (We do not make assumptions about $\theta$ and $\phi$ yet.)
\begin{align*}
|re^{i\theta} − se^{i\phi}|^2 &= (re^{i\theta} − se^{i\phi})(re^{-i\theta} − se^{-i\phi})\\
&= r^2 + s^2 − rs(e^{i(\theta−\phi)} + e^{−i(\theta−\phi)})\\
&= (r − s)^2 + 2rs(1 − \cos(\theta−\phi)).
\end{align*}
Hence if $|re^{i\theta} − se^{i\phi}|$ is sufficiently small, then $r$ and $s$ must be approximately equal (so in
particular $2s > r$) and so from the above we see that $1 − \cos(\theta−\phi)$ is small, so $\theta−\phi$ is approximately a multiple of $2\pi$. Therefore, if $\theta,\phi \in (-\pi,\pi)$ we must have $\theta\approx\phi$. //

Here is what I don't understand:

How do we conclude that $1 − \cos(\theta−\phi)$ is small? I agree that $2rs(1 − \cos(\theta−\phi)$ must be small but what if $rs$ is really small, how can we then conclude that $1 − \cos(\theta−\phi)$ is small also?

Many thanks!